# What is difference between the shape of columns titles in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sorting, phpmyadmin

I use *phpmyadmin* and I want to know why sometimes the title of column is like a **link** and sometimes else it is like a **button**, why? and what is the difference between them?

Here is two screenshot of them:

[image]

[image]

Comment: different css? A bug I guess

Comment: @Strawberry Yes exactly I mean is "different CSS". But I don't think it is bug. phpmyadmin is a great program and seems perfect

Comment: its not a bug, some query results phpmyadmin can't sort column. In that case button will show up

Comment: @eatjs ah, seems reasonable. thanks

Comment: @eatjs so there is any problem in the query?! and should I fix it?

Comment: @stack Its not like problem in query, some complex query including so many joins or sub queries can't sort with columns. Look at the query and result. You will get it why it can't be sort.